# Need help designing a query that tells how many remaining days before a payment is due

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

So I have created a Transaction table with the following columns: tID, CustID,EmpID, DateBooked.
tID is the primary key.
CustID and EmpID are foreign keys, they refer to the customer table and employee tables.

Here is the SQL query I have so far:

```
SELECT tID,DATE_ADD(DateBooked,INTERVAL 45 DAY) AS PaymentDueDate
FROM Transactions
```

The above code will add 45 days to the booked dated. What I cannot figure out is how can I find the remaining days left before the payment is due. I want to query to return some thing like, "12 days before payment is due"

I know it has something to do with DATEDIFF, but I cant figure out how to get it to work with out having to enter the two dates.

I am totally new at this so please advise if I am on the right track.

Comment: Your query is not SQL Server syntax.  You should tag the question with the appropriate database.

Comment: Have you tried getting the difference between the actual date (SQL server: getdate() ) and your added date?

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF('DateBooked')-(getdate()) AS RemainingDays
FROM Transactions
WHERE tID= 'abc123'

Im not sure if this works but im currently testing this now.

Comment: You have a SQLPLUS (Oracle) tag but MySQL syntax. Which is it?

Comment: Nick you pointed out another thing. I was using mySQL on Oracle. which is why i was having so much issues... ugh.. after I did a littler more research i found proper syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! I think I got it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Oracle (since you removed the SQL Server tag and kept the SQL*Plus tag), you wouldn't use `DATEDIFF` (which is a valid function in SQL Server but not Oracle).  You'd simply add 45 to the date.

```
SELECT tID, dateBooked + 45 as PaymentDueDate
  FROM transactions
```

If you want to use intervals, you could also

```
SELECT tID, dateBooked + interval '45' day as PaymentDueDate
  FROM transactions
```

Comment: this was it. so after tinkering with the code i found this same solution.

I got it guys !

'Select (DateBooked+45)-sysdate from Transactions;'

So this query adds the 45 days to the bookeddate then subtracts the finaldate from the systems date to give a difference. which should tell you how many days are left before a payment is due. correct ?